# Python: remove characters from a string?

Tags: python, string

I took a python course back when i was in high school but now I barely remember anything about it. I'm bored today and though I should try some python exercises.

Example:
`string = '3dc8uo8c33a v8c08oizl6ga'`

The code needs to remove 3d 8u 8c ... ect

so that the 
`answer = 'coca cola'`

Comment: What's the rule for either keeping/removing elements?

Comment: Obviously, the rule is "ect". Which I believe is short for "ectoplasm," so you should probably ask the Ghostbusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rule is "split the string along whitespace, then take every third letter of the words, and add them back together", you can use

```
>>> string = '3dc8uo8cc33a v8c08oizl6ga'
>>> " ".join("".join(s[2::3]) for s in string.split())
'coca cola'
```

Comment: Quite an assumption :) (obviously works though!)

Comment: Yes indeed :), but I couldn't find any other rule that would work here reliably...

Comment: There wasn't any rule to it. Just the end goal. Thank you

Comment: @Jutia: OK, but did you notice that I had to change your input string to make this work? :)